# What happens if I stash changes in a branch and then delete that branch

Tags: git, git-stash

What happens if I stash changes in a branch and then delete that branch?

(1) Do I lose the stashed changes?

Example:

```
git stash
git checkout other_branch
git branch -D previous_branch
```

(2) Also, are the above stash and delete steps equivalent to commiting the changes in a branch and then deleting that branch (in terms of the final state achieved) ? ie:

```
git commit -m "Dummy commit, I am terminating this branch"
git checkout other_branch
git branch -D previous_branch
```

Comment: @torek provided an excellent answer, but to be short, a stash entry does not "belong" to any branch, and any branch operations do not affect the stash--it's a completely orthogonal concept.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

(1) No.  The changes saved by `git stash` are saved as a pair (or sometimes trio) of commits.  Those commits are referenced by the name `stash`.  If you think of branch names and tags as labels for commits (which is what they *are*), then you can draw a picture, e.g.:

```
          O1 - O2             <-- other_branch
        /
M1 - M2 - M3 - M4             <-- master
   \
     B1 - B2 - B3             <-- branch
      .
       .......................<-- tag
```

(this might work better if I could color the tag differently; I used dots to suggest that the tag `tag` points to commit `B1`, which is "on branch `branch`").

If you're on branch `branch` and have some unsaved changes and run `git stash`, this is what it does:

```
        /
M1 - M2 - M3 - M4             <-- master
   \
     B1 - B2 - B3             <-- HEAD=branch
                | \
                i - w ........<-- stash
```

(I left `other_branch` and `tag` out of the diagram but they're still there too.  I wrote `HEAD=branch` to imply that `HEAD` is pointing to `branch`, and `branch` is pointing to commit `B3`.)

Here `i` and `w` are the "index" and "work-tree" states that you `stash`ed.  The name `stash` points directly at commit `w`, and `w` has two parents (i.e., is a "merge commit" even though it's not really a merge at all), with `B3` as its first parent and `i` as its second.

When you run `git branch -D`, all you are doing is erasing the label.  So let's say you `git checkout other_branch` and then erase the label `branch`.  Now you have this:

```
          O1 - O2             <-- HEAD=other_branch
        /
M1 - M2 - M3 - M4             <-- master
   \
     B1 - B2 - B3
                | \
                i - w ........<-- stash
```

There is no label directly on `B3` but the stash points to `w`, and `w` points back to `B3`.  So everything is still there, and will remain there as long as the stash (or the reflog, or both) keep `B3` on git's internal radar.

(2) No: as you can see, the stash still has a reference to the branch.  However, once you *drop* that stash—i.e., erase the `stash` label—with `git stash drop` for instance—you get this:

```
          O1 - O2             <-- HEAD=other_branch
        /
M1 - M2 - M3 - M4             <-- master
   \
     B1 - B2 - B3
                | \
                i - w
```

Had you `git add`-ed and `git commit`ed all your changes, you would have gotten a (single, non-merge) commit, which we could call `B4`, on `branch`.  The branch label would have been moved to point to `B4`, and then you would check out `other_branch` and delete the label, giving:

```
          O1 - O2             <-- HEAD=other_branch
        /
M1 - M2 - M3 - M4             <-- master
   \
     B1 - B2 - B3 - B4
```

which is almost (but not quite) the same.

(Note that if tag `tag` still points to `B1`, commit `B1` will stick around until the tag is also erased.  Commits `B2` through `B4`, or `B2` through `w`, will only stick around as long as they stay there-but-invisible in the reflog.  After 30 days (or whatever you set for reflog expiry), the reflog entries expire, and those commits become eligible for garbage collection.)

Answer (score 10):

1. Stashing takes the dirty state of your working directory and saves it on a stack.  If you stash something and then delete the previous branch, your stashed changes does not vanish.  You can list what's on stash stack with the command :

git stash list

In fact, You can save a stash, switch to another branch, and try reapply the stash.  Applying the stash on the same branch is not necessary.

In second case,  You still need to do git commit after applying stash.